# Puzzled about how to extend an S3 class from the package 'XML'

Tags: xml, r, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to extend an S3 object from the package XML. My understanding of S3 classes is that R looks for the correct function to apply for each class in the class vector, going from left to right, moving on to the next if the function is not defined for the current class. So for example, with an `lm` object:

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
x <- lm(weight ~ group)
pryr::otype(x)
```

[1] "S3"

```
class(x) <- append("MyLMClass", class(x)) # adding class
print.MyLMClass <- function(x) cat("this is from MyLMClass") # overriding print
x
```

this is from MyLMClass

`summary()` is not defined for `MyLMClass` but calling it on `x` does work, since `R` moves on to the next class, which is `lm`:

```
summary(x)
```

Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ group)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.0710 -0.4938  0.0685  0.2462  1.3690

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   5.0320     0.2202  22.850 9.55e-15 ***

(etc..)

---

But this doesn't work for XML objects:

```
library(XML)
someXML <- newXMLNode("a")
newXMLNode("g", 3, parent = someXML)
newXMLNode("c", 5, parent = someXML)
someXML

<a>
  <g>3</g>
  <c>5</c>
</a>
pryr::otype(someXML)
[1] "S3"
```

And `getNodeSet(someXML, "/a/c/")[[1]]` gives:

```
<c>5</c>
```

But as soon as I add a new class to it, nothing works, not even print:

```
> class(someXML) <- append("MyClass", class(someXML))
> someXML
Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'character'

> getNodeSet(someXML,"/a/c")[[1]]
Error in as(doc, "XMLInternalDocument") : 
  no method or default for coercing “MyClass” to “XMLInternalDocument”
```

I want to be able to extend the XML object so that:

- I can directly use all the functions from the package XML without having to redefine them for each new class I'm designing.
- I can define new functions for my new classes (e.g. MyClass) and override existing functions for more specialised classes (e.g. MyClass2, sub-class of MyClass, sub-class of the XML object)

How can I achieve this?

(It appears that `getNodeSet()` is not an S3 generic, which probably explains why it doesn't work on the new class.)

---

EDIT:
Casting `someXML` to an `XMLDocument` makes `getNodeSet()` work:

```
someXML <- newXMLNode("a")
newXMLNode("g", 3, parent = someXML)
newXMLNode("c", 5, parent = someXML)
someXML <- newXMLDoc(someXML) # <== that's new
class(someXML) <- append("MyClass", class(someXML))
class(someXML) <- append("MyClass2", class(someXML))
getNodeSet(someXML,"/a/c")[[1]]
<c>5</c>
```

but `print()` still doesn't work:

```
someXML
Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'character'
```

Comment: Pretty sure XML used S4 classes in many places.

Comment: `pryr::otype(someXML)` gives me `S3` in both cases (either with or without the `XMLDocument` cast).